# Questions about Hosting customers' ASP.NET sites

Tags: asp.net, hosting

Where do you host your customers' ASP.NET sites? I am about to develop a few sites, and I am looking for a good place to host (cheap, fast, good bandwidth, good storage, updates, service packs, etc.)

I have also thought about earning revenue for the hosting/domain, even though I am not actually hosting it (kinda sounds bad when you put it out there). Basically, I would just handle the hosting/domain costs and bill the customer, with a bit of markup. They wont know anything about the host, unless they go digging. Does anyone else incorporate this into their business model? What are the pros/cons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like [webhost4life](http://www.webhost4life.com/).  I've tried hosting customer stuff -- you can't charge them enough to deal with the pain.  It's much better to give it up to somebody else to deal with the bandwidth and SLAs.

Comment: +1 for webhost4life, use then for 6 month, very happy with service.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Brinkster](http://www.brinkster.com) for several years & never had any unplanned outages or any real problems.  Keep in mind that the sites I've worked on aren't high-volume sites (local restaurants, etc) so I haven't really pushed the envelope bandwidth-wise.  Pricing is good & support has always helped me out when I needed it.

A note on marking up hosting...I'm a one-person shop & I tried this once (for a short time), and regretted it immediately.  Every tiny email issue, Outlook configuration setting, etc. will result in a customer phone call to you. YMMV, but the markup was never profitable or worthwhile for me personally.

Answer (score 0):

[Peer1](http://www.peer1.com/) is a bit expensive but offers an excellent support when something goes wrong (DNS, email, dabase, service pack...). They help you configure your server and take care of security aspects (amongmany others).

I also use [ServerBeach](http://www.serverbeach.com/) (Peer1's little brother), its self-managed hosting which means you have to take care yourself of the security, the server's configuration, the service packs,... more flexible and less expensive. Support is also excellent.